# How to unlock android camera after it is crashed?

Tags: android, camera, mediarecorder

I created a video recording app using android MediaRecorder. I notice that some time, for whatever reason the app crashes while I am recording a video, the camera would get locked.

When the camera is locked, I cannot open it from another other camera app. I cannot unlocked it by killing, or deleting the app.

Now is there any way, I can programmatically force the android camer to unlock it self from the previous app so then I can use it on my app? Or is there any precaution that I should take to prevent my app from locking up the camera?

thanks for reading and would appreciate any comments or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not releasing the instance of the camera. You might want to do

```
protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if(cameraObj!=null)
            {
                cameraObj.release();        
                    cameraObj=null;
            }           

     }
```

Figure out the reason for crash. For using the camera again, I usually just restart the device and it works.